# I have written code for Screen recorder in python but when I play video it is fast how too solve?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have written code for Screen recorder in python but when I play video it is fast how too solve?

```
import cv2

import numpy as np
import os
import pyautogui
import keyboard

output = "video.avi"
img = pyautogui.screenshot()
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
#get info from img
height, width, channels = img.shape
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, 30.0, (width, height))

while(True):
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    out.write(image)
    cv2.waitKey(30)
    # StopIteration(0.5)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How to play at normal time?

Comment: What have you done in terms of debugging?

Comment: If you record images at a slower rate than they are played back they will appear too fast. You need to ensure that the recording and playback rates are the same.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: I mean not getin calculations correct and I want to record at normal time only

Answer (score 2):

I solved something similar to this by adjusting the speed that it writes the image to the mpg.

The 30 FPS you set in the videowriter is for playback, not input speed. Right now your while loop is going to write frames as fast as it can

At 30 FPS, i would have to write a frame every 1/30th of a second. Any more and it will seem slow, and any less and it will seem fast.

I wrote something inside of my while True loop, that only writes a new frame if 1/30th of a second or more has passed.

Also waitkey should be 0 if you want to update the frame manually, or 1 if you want it to update itself. I am unfamiliar with waitkey being anything other than 0 or 1.

EDIT: just looked it up. I think if you put your waitkey as .03 ( which is 1/30) you will get what you want.